# Create a histogram of the top 10 words that appear in a text file

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a histogram of the frequency (in percentages) that the top ten words in a text appear.
It needs to be in similar format to this this:

for: --------------------20(percent and 20 dashes)

is: ---------------15

him: ----------10

war: -----5

have: -----5

hero: -----5

have: ----4

girl: -----5

angry: ----4

others: --------------------------------32

I know I need a for loop of 10, and inside it another loop with dashes going to the percent

int main()
{

```
string file_name;
cout << "Enter the file name, the odyssey or pride and prejudice, that you would like to analyze: ";
getline(cin,file_name);

vector<string> words; //loading words into vector called words
if(file_name == "test")
{
    words = words_to_vector("test.txt"); //used a test files so it would take less time
}
else if(file_name == "pride and prejudice")
{
    words = words_to_vector("pride-prejudice.txt");
}
else if (file_name == "the odyssey")
{
    words = words_to_vector("the-odyssey.txt");
}
else
{
    cout << "Sorry, the file name you entered is invalid.";
}

vector<word_stats> stats = get_word_stats(words); // calculating the number of words, and how many of those words are unique

cout << endl << endl << "Total words: " << words.size() << ", " << stats.size() << " unique" << endl;

sort(stats.begin(), stats.end(), compare_stats);

cout << "Most common word is '" << stats[0].word << "' occuring " << stats[0].count << " times." << endl;


int topMostCount = 10; //where I need help putting this into a histogram
//int totalWords = words.size();
int totalUniqueWords = stats.size();
//most common
for (int i=0; i<stats.size() && i<topMostCount; i++) {
    cout << stats[i].word << ": " << stats[i].count << endl;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need an algorithm to convert the percentage to 'dashes'. You have the total number of unique words, `tWords`. What is the total number of words? You have the count of each word `stat[i].count`. What is the percentage of words represented in `stat[i].count`? Get the integer value of the percentage and use this value to output that many dashes. How to calculate the percentage of words left over after the first 10 unique words? Break the problem down in to TINY parts. Solve each part. Put the parts together.

Comment: You could use a pair (key, value) structure where the key would be some word and the value would be the number of occurrences. Finding the top and average would be easy then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you create a method to generate dashes and output it as a const char *?

```
for(int i = 0; i < stats.size() && i < topMostCount; i++){
    int percent = (double)stats[i].count / words.size * 100.00;
    const char * dashes = genDashes(percent);
    cout << stats[i].word << ": " << dashes << percent << "%";
}
```

And the genDashes function would be something as follow:

```
const char * genDashes(int n)
{
    std::stringstream ss_dashes;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        ss_dashes << "-";
    }
    std::string s_dashes = ss_dashes.str();
    return s_dashes.c_str();
}
```